# How to limit a bone between other two bones, for scale and position

Tags: armature, constraints

I have this situation:

[image]

I want the bone "A" to always be between the other two bones, extension included. This bone receives user movement, grab and scale, using any number of extra bones.

I already tried to give bone "A" constraints like `Floor` and that worked nice, but it doesn't work for the other handle of the bone.

[image]

This second image show an auto adjustment making this effect, using `Floor` and  `Stretch`, but the interaction bone (the selected one) lacks for limits in it's extreme, making it imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I'll take a guess:

If you want A's base to be at B's base and A's tip to be at C's base, you might benefit from drivers.

Unfortunately, the expressions to map from B and C to the proper pose for A would not be trivial.

Also, [blender has some shortcomings in its dependency system that prevents intra-armature drivers from being calculated correctly in some circumstances.](https://developer.blender.org/T40301)